# How do you delete all files from the windows Temp folder using C#? (When the processes are running)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, process

```
private void Clean_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process processes = new Process();

    var temp_path = @"C:\Windows\Temp";
    var temp_files = Directory.GetDirectories(temp_path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    foreach (var temp_file in temp_files)
    {
        Process.GetProcesses();
        processes.Kill();
        File.Delete(temp_file);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to delete all the files and folders from the Temp folder in Windows. But it throws an error that processes are running.

Comment: I doesn't seem to be a great idea. Even if it is possible, killing processes whatever they are just to delete files that they need to have for their own work seems to be a right path to a system crash. What is the reason for this effort?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Just curious - if you'd written an app that needed to use files in the temp folder, and some other app came along and deleted them while your app was still trying to use them, what would your first thought be?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely impossible. Deleting the running processes will probably terminate C++ aswell, and thus your script won't work.